# "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" error on Joomla website

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am experiencing a strange issue on a Joomla 2.5.4 site: http://tinyurl.com/k8xuxth

One of our employees made a few front-end edits to two or three pages and now some of the pages randomly redirect to an error message:

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
>       moments.
>
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
>       connection.
>
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
>       that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

It does not happen all the time, and it never happens on the home page. If you click on the "Class Schedule" or "About" links in the nav, it should throw the error message for you. In Chrome, it appears to just freeze up completely. Sometimes, in FireFox, you can see the page begin to load before it redirects to the above error message.

I can't seem to find any errors in any logs. It was a Joomla 1.7 site, but yesterday I upgraded it to the 2.5.4 and also installed K2 and converted all of the Articles to K2 "Items"... neither of these fixed the issue. I am stumped! Any feedback/help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Other things I tried:

- Disabling all modules.
- Disabling select plugins (such as Google Analytics).
- Upgrading select plugins and modules.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the "Content - Load Modules" plugin might have been the culprit. Not sure why that would suddenly "go bad" though...

Comment: IF there was a bad module loaded that could be a problem. Also it shouldn't happen but if a module in loadposition loads the article that is it loaded in that can create a looping situation.

Comment: The modules being loaded were simply HTML modules... they had an <img> and that's about it. Nothing fancy.